# Can I add UITabBarController in UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, xcode4.5

I have two menu, first (it is main)horizontal and second(click on second button of first menu) vertical. I want do first menu use UITabBarController and second menu use UITabBarController too.

**Can I do it?**

**How do custom functionality which will be change controllers second menu?**

**Can App Store reject this app by this functionality?**

Comment: why don't you use UITabbar instead of Tabbar controller for second time? And I doubt whether application will look good, with tab bar all over screen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can App Store reject this app by this functionality?

maybe, pay attention to 10.3 and 10.6:

[image: app store rules section 10]